# Set Additional Data to highcharts series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

is there any way to pass some additional data to the series object that will use to show in the chart 'tooltip'?

for example

```
 tooltip: {
     formatter: function() {
               return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
           Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e', this.x) +': '+ this.y;
     }
```

here we can only use series.name , this.x & this.y to the series. lets say i need to pass another dynamic value alone with the data set and can access via series object. is this possible?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Javascript isn't picky about which objects you pass along, and usually ignores them if they aren't used.  They might be stripped out by the library's internal code, but they aren't necessarily, and it is usually worth a shot.  Have you tried appending additional data to your `series` object, and displaying it in this handler?

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham - I am new to 'HighCharts'. can you please post any link that i can find kind of example thing? thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: @Sam, my answer has a full working example that you can take a look at. Let me know if it doesn't quite meet your requirements.

Comment: How can I add additional data like myData in case of bubble chart as the data array is like data : [[12, 43, 13], [74, 23, 44]] e.g. what are the keys for the data values like the above has 'y', are there 'x', 'y' and 'z' ? or 'size'

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Yes, if you set up the series object like the following, where each data point is a hash, then you can pass extra values:

```
new Highcharts.Chart( {
    ...,
    series: [ {
        name: 'Foo',
        data: [
            {
                y : 3,
                myData : 'firstPoint'
            },
            {
                y : 7,
                myData : 'secondPoint'
            },
            {
                y : 1,
                myData : 'thirdPoint'
            }
        ]
    } ]
} );
```

In your tooltip you can access it via the "point" attribute of the object passed in:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return 'Extra data: <b>' + this.point.myData + '</b>';
    }
}
```

Full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/burwelldesigns/jeoL5y7s/

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but fiddle linked no longer shows the relevant example.

Comment: @undefinedvariable - hmm, looks like others have edited this and set a new version as the "base" version in jsfiddle. That's unfortunate. Updated the fiddle and now linking to a specific version in the answer.

Comment: @Nick, awesome, thanks. Great answer, by the way. I was running out of unused default values to sneak information in.

Comment: How to access myData if its an array ?

Comment: @user1191081 not sure I understand your question.. but you could make myData an array like this: { y : 3, myData : [ 'foo', 'bar' ] }  and then you can access by this.point.myData[0] and this.point.myData[1], etc.

Comment: Thanks, How can I add additional data like myData in case of bubble chart as the data array is like data : [[12, 43, 13], [74, 23, 44]] e.g. what are the keys for the data values like the above has 'y', are there 'x', 'y' and 'z' ? or 'size' ?

Comment: Thats working. If I put one more layer where I am trying to apply DataGrouping for unit week, additional data's are NOT GETTING grouped.

Comment: Is this at all possible with a series instead of data?  For example, have myData be placed like so: series[{ name:'foo', myData: 'bar', data:[{...}] }]; I cannot get it to work in the way that I just described

Comment: This may not work if your time series contains more than 1000 points, which I believe is the default turboThreshold, and increasing that threshold doesn't solve it.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but fiddle linked no longer exist throwing 404

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan thanks for the heads up on the broken link.. I added a new fiddle that works again

Answer (score 17):

Additionally, with this solution, you can even **put multiple data as much as you want** :

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return 'Extra data: <b>' + this.point.myData + '</b><br> Another Data: <b>' + this.point.myOtherData + '</b>';
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'Foo',
    data: [{
        y: 3,
        myData: 'firstPoint',
        myOtherData: 'Other first data'
    }, {
        y: 7,
        myData: 'secondPoint',
        myOtherData: 'Other second data'
    }, {
        y: 1,
        myData: 'thirdPoint',
        myOtherData: 'Other third data'
    }]
}]
```

Thank you Nick.

Comment: The 'additional data' isn't possible when the [x, y] non-object format is used? We have `datetime` as x-value but want to add extra data to the tooltip.

Comment: Example for timeseries data :

var serie = {x:Date.parse(d.Value), y:d.Item, method:d.method };

Comment: How to achieve this on android ?

Answer (score 17):

For time series data, especially with enough data points to activate the [turbo threshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.turboThreshold), the proposed solutions above will not work. In the case of the turbo threshold, this is because Highcarts expects the data points to be an array like:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Numbers over the course of time',
    data: [
      [1515059819853, 1],
      [1515059838069, 2],
      [1515059838080, 3],
      // you get the idea
    ]
  }]
```

In order not to lose the benefits of the turbo threshold (which is important when dealing with lots of data points), I store the data outside of the chart and look up the data point in the tooltip `formatter` function. Here's an example:

```
const chartData = [
  { timestamp: 1515059819853, value: 1, somethingElse: 'foo'},
  { timestamp: 1515059838069, value: 2, somethingElse: 'bar'},
  { timestamp: 1515059838080, value: 3, somethingElse: 'baz'},
  // you get the idea
]

const Chart = Highcharts.stockChart(myChart, {
  // ...options
  tooltip: {
    formatter () {
      // this.point.x is the timestamp in my original chartData array
      const pointData = chartData.find(row => row.timestamp === this.point.x)
      console.log(pointData.somethingElse)
    }
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'Numbers over the course of time',
      // restructure the data as an array as Highcharts expects it
      // array index 0 is the x value, index 1 is the y value in the chart
      data: chartData.map(row => [row.timestamp, row.value])
    }]
})
```

This approach will work for all chart types.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, it's really helpful for displaying additional data in High Stock graphs.

Comment: Shouldn't `data: _.map(data, row => [row['timestamp'], row['value']])` be `data: chartData.map(row => [row.timestamp, row.value])`? Also, you don't need lodash; you can use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). It's not supported by IE, but you're using ES6 already (`const`) and [MS stopped supporting IE in 2016](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/ie11-largely-doesnt-support-es6-shouldnt-this-be-mentioned-somewhere).

Comment: Good catch with `chartData`. I'm used to using lodash but you're right. I updated my example so it's library agnostic. thx.

Answer (score 3):

I am using AJAX to get my data from SQL Server, then I prepare a js array that is used as the data in my chart.
JavaScript code once the AJAX is successfull:

```
...,
success: function (data) {
            var fseries = [];
            var series = [];
            for (var arr in data) {
                for (var i in data[arr]['data'] ){
                    var d = data[arr]['data'][i];
                    //if (i < 5) alert("d.method = " + d.method);
                    var serie = {x:Date.parse(d.Value), y:d.Item, method:d.method };
                    series.push(serie);
                }
                fseries.push({name: data[arr]['name'], data: series, location: data[arr]['location']});
                series = [];
            };
            DrawChart(fseries);
         },
```

Now to show extra meta-data in the tooltip:

```
...
tooltip: {
    xDateFormat: '%m/%d/%y',
    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
    pointFormat: 'Method: {point.method}<br>Date: {point.x:%m/%d/%y } <br>Reading: {point.y:,.2f}',
    shared: false,
},
```

I use a DataRow to iterate through my result set, then I use a class to assign the values prior to passing back in Json format. Here is the C# code in the controller action called by Ajax.

```
public JsonResult ChartData(string dataSource, string locationType, string[] locations, string[] methods, string fromDate, string toDate, string[] lstParams)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> dataResult = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> aSeries = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    string currParam = string.Empty;        

    lstParams = (lstParams == null) ? new string[1] : lstParams;
    foreach (DataRow dr in GetChartData(dataSource, locationType, locations, methods, fromDate, toDate, lstParams).Rows)
    {
        if (currParam != dr[1].ToString())
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currParam))       //A new Standard Parameter is read and add to dataResult. Skips first record.
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> bSeries = new Dictionary<string, object>(aSeries); //Required else when clearing out aSeries, dataResult values are also cleared
                dataResult.Add(bSeries);
                aSeries.Clear();
            }
            currParam = dr[1].ToString(); 
            aSeries["name"] = cParam;
            aSeries["data"] = new List<ChartDataModel>();
            aSeries["location"] = dr[0].ToString();
        }

        ChartDataModel lst = new ChartDataModel();
        lst.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[3]).ToShortDateString();
        lst.Item = Convert.ToDouble(dr[2]);
        lst.method = dr[4].ToString();
        ((List<ChartDataModel>)aSeries["data"]).Add(lst);
    }
    dataResult.Add(aSeries);
    var result = Json(dataResult.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  //used to debug final dataResult before returning to AJAX call.
    return result;
}
```

I realize there is a more efficient and acceptable way to code in C# but I inherited the project.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some kind of dynamism :

Did this for generating data for a stacked column chart with 10 categories.
I wanted to have for each category 4 data series and wanted to display additional information (image, question, distractor and expected answer) for each of the data series :

```
<?php 

while($n<=10)
{
    $data1[]=array(
        "y"=>$nber1,
        "img"=>$image1,
        "ques"=>$ques,
        "distractor"=>$distractor1,
        "answer"=>$ans
    );
    $data2[]=array(
        "y"=>$nber2,
        "img"=>$image2,
        "ques"=>$ques,
        "distractor"=>$distractor2,
        "answer"=>$ans
    );
    $data3[]=array(
        "y"=>$nber3,
        "img"=>$image3,
        "ques"=>$ques,
        "distractor"=>$distractor3,
        "answer"=>$ans
    );
    $data4[]=array(
        "y"=>$nber4,
        "img"=>$image4,
        "ques"=>$ques,
        "distractor"=>$distractor4,
        "answer"=>$ans
    );
}

// Then convert the data into data series:

$mydata[]=array(
    "name"=>"Distractor #1",
    "data"=>$data1,
    "stack"=>"Distractor #1"
);
$mydata[]=array(
    "name"=>"Distractor #2",
    "data"=>$data2,
    "stack"=>"Distractor #2"
);
$mydata[]=array(
    "name"=>"Distractor #3",
    "data"=>$data3,
    "stack"=>"Distractor #3"
);
$mydata[]=array(
    "name"=>"Distractor #4",
    "data"=>$data4,
    "stack"=>"Distractor #4"
);
?>
```

**In the highcharts section:**

```
var mydata=<? echo json_encode($mydata)?>;

// Tooltip section
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {

            return 'Question ID: <b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                   'Question: <b>'+ this.point.ques +'</b><br/>'+
                   this.series.name+'<br> Total attempts: '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                   "<img src=\"images/"+ this.point.img +"\" width=\"100px\" height=\"50px\"/><br>"+
                   'Distractor: <b>'+ this.point.distractor +'</b><br/>'+
                   'Expected answer: <b>'+ this.point.answer +'</b><br/>';
               }
           },

// Series section of the highcharts 
series: mydata
// For the category section, just prepare an array of elements and assign to the category variable as the way I did it on series.
```

Hope it helps someone.