# Add additional data to a Highcharts series for use in formatters

Tags: highcharts

My question is exactly the same as the OP in this question:

[Set Additional Data to highcharts series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514457/set-additional-data-to-highcharts-series)

But the accepted answer explains how to add additional data to the *point*, not the series, without saying if it's possible to do with the series or not.

I would like to be able to define a series like:

```
series: [
    {"hasCustomFlag": true, "name": "s1", "data": [...]},
    {"hasCustomFlag": false, "name": "s2", "data": [...]},
]
```

and be able to use `point.series.hasCustomFlag` inside of a formatting function.  Is this possible?

I don't want to put the data on the point level, because that means I'd have to duplicate the data far too many times.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes this is possible, the extra configuration properties is located under the `options` property (`this.series` refers to the series instance, not the configuration objects). See the reference [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series#2) and scroll down to properties section.

So instead use this line in the formatter:

```
if (this.series.options.hasCustomFlag) { ... }
```

Full example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvfnoymu/1/)

Comment: Ahh, I hadn't made the connection as to what the options object was.  Worked like a charm - Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 3):

This appears to have been revised with later iterations of HighCharts/HighStocks. The jsfiddle example no longer works.  Using the "this.series.options.hasCustomFlag" syntax results in "undefined". The debugger shows the data I'm looking for is in "this.series.userOptions.data" - an unsorted very large array, but the entire series is there - not the specific record data you normally get with this.x or this.y.

Comment: It does still work if you get the proper latest highcharts.js script, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/jNXV8/51/

Comment: I've updated it again to use https to load Highcharts, doesn't work without. https://jsfiddle.net/jNXV8/70/