# Javascript syntax when setting a value

Tags: javascript, syntax, highcharts

I was looking at this question: [Add additional data to a Highcharts series for use in formatters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752141/add-additional-data-to-a-highcharts-series-for-use-in-formatters)

I want to add hasCustomFlag variable also, but I want it dynamically.

I tried like this:

```
this.series[0].setOptions("hasCustomFlag ",data.someList);
```

But it's not working. This is how I'm setting the data:

```
chart1.series[0].setData(data.someList);
```

Comment: Did you try with the syntax used in the answer to the example you link to?

Comment: @DaveNewton This: http://jsfiddle.net/jNXV8/ is not dynamically.

Comment: If you are not worry about the fact, that `options` of the series is declared as `read-only` in HighCharts documentation, you can just make something like this: `chart1.series[0].options.hasCustomFlag = true`

Comment: What do you mean with "dynaimcally"? *When* do you want to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
chart1.series[0].hasCustomFlag = data.someList;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define series in the chart object , it initially counts from 0 , so you don't hv to parse the series name inside ,

```
chart.series[0].setData(array);
```