# Custom axis labels on Stacked bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I am generating a standard stacked bar chart for a client.  But what they want for the yAxis label is not the sum of the values of the two stacked bars.  This is easy is a simple bar chart, but in a stacked chart it always takes the total of the two.  My existing code is:

```
return Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.round(this.total*100)/100, 2) + '%';
```

I'm setting the number I need to display in the data string like this:

```
data: [{y: 1.83, color: '#BBBBBB', 'QTotal': 3.37}
```

Where 'QTotal' is the value they want to display.  I've tried the following with no luck:

```
return Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.round(this.QTotal*100)/100, 2) + '%';
return Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.round(this.point.QTotal*100)/100, 2) + '%';
return Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.round(this.y.QTotal*100)/100, 2) + '%';
```

Setting up fixed labels doesn't work cause the number of bars being shown is flexible. Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you should access the extra data using:

```
return Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.round(this.series.options.QTotal*100)/100, 2) + '%';
```

See also this answer: [Add additional data to a Highcharts series for use in formatters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752141/add-additional-data-to-a-highcharts-series-for-use-in-formatters/8758914#8758914)

And this one: [Set Additional Data to highcharts series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514457/set-additional-data-to-highcharts-series)