# Add additional data to point using DotNet.Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am learning how to use HighCharts with Visual Studio.  I am using DotNet.Highcharts to hopfully make it easier.  I have a series with the y value of totalAttempts which is and integer and the x value of DateTime.  The series is a spline chart.  I would like to add additional data.

How can I add additional data to each point using DotNet.Highcharts?

**UPDATE**

I have a Series List that I use to add all of the needed Series to:

```
List<Series> mySeries = new List<Series>();
```

I use an array list to hold each of the data points needed

```
var myResults = new List<object[]>();
```

Then I loop through the results of a query several time to gather the data for each point of a Series.  Here is the code I use:

```
myResults.Add(new object[] 
{ 
        detailRecords.groupedDate, //represents x
        detailRecords.totalAttempts //represents y
});
```

Then after the data points are all created, I then add the array list as the data for a Series

```
mySeries.Add(new Series
{
    Name = mainRecords.name,
    Data = new Data(myResults.ToArray())
});
```

What I don't know how to do is add additional information to the data points so I can display it when it is hovered over.  The question [Set Additional Data to highcharts series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514457/set-additional-data-to-highcharts-series) shows how to do this but I can't seem to get it working with DotNet.Highcharts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment it's not possible to add such kind of additional data by using DotNet.Highcharts. But this is a good feature and it will be included at the next releases of the library.

Comment: Hey Vangi, I am taking it you are the person that wrote the DotNet.Highcharts to make easy to integrate Highcharts with Visual Studio.  I like it a lot.  It is easy to use and it works really well.  To be able to create a variable name and value for each additional data piece at the Series or Point level would make it a perfect charting solution for me.  **How difficult would it be to add that feature?  When do you expect the next release of the library to be available?  How can I be notified when it is released?**

Comment: I don't know how complex can be this feature and I don't know when you can expect the next release, there is not fixed date. You can follow the project in codeplex page to notify for any changes.