# highcharts pass multiple values to tooltip

Tags: javascript, tooltip, highcharts

I need to display 3 values on the tooltip:
the time, the value and another value(change).

I saw [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick) (but the jsdfiddle is not working).

I tried this

```
//each loop..
indice.push(["time", "value1", "value2"]);
```

, the tooltip settings

```
tooltip:
    {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function()
    {
      return '' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x) +'; '+ this.y + this.z(<-is this right?);
    }
},
```

and the series

```
series:
[{
    type: 'area',
    data: indice
}]
```

can somone help pls?
thsnks.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what result do you want ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Additional Data to highcharts series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514457/set-additional-data-to-highcharts-series)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you want to pass additional data for a point other than the x and y values, then you have to name that value.  In the following [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6tc6T/3/) I add the following three additional values to each data point:

```
{
  y: 3,
  locked: 1,
  unlocked: 1,
  potential: 1,
}
```

Then to access and display those values in the tooltip I use the following:

```
tooltip: 
{
     formatter: function() { return ' ' +
        'Locked: ' + this.point.locked + '<br />' +
        'Unlocked: ' + this.point.unlocked + '<br />' +
        'Potential: ' + this.point.potential;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you, in a multi series Highstocks chart, want to display series specific data in the tooltip you could do something like this.

```
var series = [];

// Populate our series
series.push({
  name: "small_cities",
  displayName: "Small Cities",
  color: "#123456",
  data: [...]
});
series.push({
  name: "Countries",
  displayName: "Countries",
  color: "#987654",
  data: [...]
});

chart: {
  ...

  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      var s = '';
      $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
        s += '<br /><span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' +
             point.series.userOptions.displayName + '</span>: ' + point.y;
      });
      return s;
    }
  },

  ...
}
```

Now you'll see nice series names "Small Cities" instead of the series.name (small_cities). All attributes you set on the series can be found in `this.points[].series.userOptions`.
For more formatter options take a look at the [Highstocks docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter).

Comment: `userOptions` this keyword saves my day!

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out, 
I pass 3 values in the data array

```
indice.push([(new Date(value.x)).getTime(), val_change[0], val_change[1]]);
```

series:
    [{
      type: 'area',
     name: titleindice,
     data: indice,
     showInLegend : false //disable the the show/hide icon
   }]

and in the tooltip

```
tooltip:
                {
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function()
                    {
                        var color = "";

                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x) + this.y +  this.point.config[2] ;

                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 5):

two ways.

## 1

```
series: [
          { ...
            tooltip:
              {pointFormat: "<span style=\"color:{series.color}\">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} {y2}</b><br/>"}
          }, ...          
         ]
o = Highcharts.Point.prototype.tooltipFormatter
Highcharts.Point.prototype.tooltipFormatter=function(format){return o.call(this, format).replace("{y2}", this.config[2]);}
```

## 2

```
 a = new Highcharts.StockChart(options); 
 a.series[0].tooltipFormatter = function(item) { return "<span style=\"color:{" + item.series.color+"\">" +item.series.name+"</span>: <b>"+item.y+item.point.config[2]+"</b><br/>"; }
```

Answer (score 4):

What i have tried is concatenating series name with x-axis and y-axis value and it works fine for me. What issue you are facing?

```
tooltip: { formatter: function () { return this.x + ': ' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y; } }
```

Comment: i meant in addition to the series name , a total of 4 values x,y, name and another one.

Comment: Yes you can just for demo i try this...  return this.series.name +' : '+ this.x +': '+ this.y+' : '+this.x;