# "this.point.config" is not working anymore in highcharts tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I have the same problem posted in the post : [**highcharts pass multiple values to tooltip**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294326/highcharts-pass-multiple-values-to-tooltip)

I want to pass data to tooltip but `this.point.config[2]` is not working.
Also I found [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/FuyTC/2/) example. It's not working there too

```
    formatter: function() {
    return 'param1: '+this.point.config[2] + 'param2: '+this.point.config[3];
```

can you please help me

Comment: Can you share with us, your code in jsFiddle or jsBin ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass in extra values into the tool tip, the data series needs to be list of objects rather than list of values:

```
data: [
    {
        x: 7, 
        y: 10, 
        config1: 'test',     // our custom data
        config2: 'test2'     // our custom data
    }, 
    {
        x:10, 
        y:20, 
        config1: 'test3',    // our custom data
        config2: 'test4'     // our custom data
    }
]
```

So in your Highcharts `formatter` function you can reference the custom parameters eg. `config1` and `config2` (you can use whatever name you want really) :

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return 'param1: '+this.point.config1 + '<br/>param2: '+this.point.config2;
    }
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FuyTC/8/