# Display in a tooltip data from a json in a Highcharts' pie

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, tooltip, pie-chart

I display a chart of type pie which display 2 percentages. I want to modify what it is diplay in my tooltip to display something from my JSON. My JSON look like

`{"object1":{"percentage": 0.7, "numberOfObject": 167}, "object2":{"percentage": 0.3, "numberOfObject": 125}}`

The pie display the percentage like that:

`jsonValue.object1.percentage` and `jsonValue.object2.percentage`

I want to display in my tooltip "numberOfObject" for each object when I put my mouse on its parts of the chart.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294326/highcharts-pass-multiple-values-to-tooltip). Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514457/set-additional-data-to-highcharts-series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the tooltip:

`tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                if (this.point.name === 'object 1')
                    return '<b>' + jsonValue.object1.numberOfObject + '</b>';
                else
                    return '<b>' + jsonValue.object2.numberOfObject + '</b>';
            }
}`

and for the data:

```
data: [
                ['object 1', jsonValue.object1.percentage],
                ['object2', jsonValue.object2.percentage]
]
```