# How to Add Extra Information in Hover/Tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I want to add extra information in hover/tooltip in below shared highcharts links.

Please check and help.

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown

Comment: Not sure what you have tried so far (as you have showed no code) but take a look at the API docs for data format (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data) and tooltip formatter function (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass values to tooltip which not in x and y axis in highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535238/how-to-pass-values-to-tooltip-which-not-in-x-and-y-axis-in-highcharts)

Answer (score 0):

Did similar thing by using tooltip point formatter. Added the data as a different property "tooltipData" in series object, and later used it in the formatter and modified tooltip accordingly.

Link: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: Update you post with relevant example.