# Highcharts with datetime and also additional data (tooltip text)

Tags: datetime, tooltip, highcharts

I found info how to add tooltip with additional data.
I found info how to plot a line with date format on x-axis.
Only problem I need a combination of this.

[Set Additional Data to highcharts series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514457/set-additional-data-to-highcharts-series)

```
data: [ { y : 3, myData : 'firstPoint' },
        { y : 7, myData : 'secondPoint' },
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series

I tried this:

```
data: [[Date.UTC(2012, 9, 29) , 45, 'my note' ],[Date.UTC(2012, 9, 29) , 54, 'boe' ]
```

But unfortunately not working.

Answer (score 3):

Your custom data needs to be an `Object` and not `array`
What you have used is an array

```
data: [[Date.UTC(2012, 9, 29) , 45, 'my note' ],[Date.UTC(2012, 9, 29) , 54, 'boe' ]]
```

Use an object instead

```
data:[{
 x: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 29) , 
 y: 45, 
 myData: 'my note' 
},
{
 x: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 29) , 
 y: 54, 
 myData: 'boe' 
}]
```