# Adding new data to highchart tooltip

Tags: tooltip, highcharts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set Additional Data to highcharts series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514457/set-additional-data-to-highcharts-series)

So I have this graph: http://jsfiddle.net/Gg3ZL/

And I want to replace in the tooltip where it currently says "Total Players Online" with new data from another

```
Array= ['PlayerX, PlayerY, PlayerZ', 'Player1, Player2, Player3'];
```

etc

So that it matches with the very first result in the first series data entry....

Even better if I didn't have to replace the "Total Players Online: " and instead just had another new entry in the tooltip like "Who's Online: ".

Basically mouse over an entry and see which players were online at that particular time on the tooltip.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You want to show all N no. of Player named in the tooltip. What if you have 50 names ? Tool tip size will be much more.

Comment: Yeh there that, and not to mention the amount of data for it all overtime... but that part wouldn't be viewed public and the result selection would be smaller. And for the tooltip size well I'd just use a smaller font.

Comment: @HardikMishra yes the tooltip may bloat a lot, but I think now highcharts allows a completely HTMLly tooltip so you can have things like scrollbar and all, PS: not tried it myself yet

Comment: @HardikMishra tada.... http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/WqAuE/ :)

Comment: Zooming is just one of the ways, with css and javascript, better visualizations like pagination,etc can be achieved if showing the players' list is a must use case

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can attach the additional data with each point in the **[`series.data`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.data)** as follows

```
series: [{
    name: 'Series 1',
    data: [{
        y: 2,
        players: ['a', 'b']},
    {
        y: 3,
        players: ['a', 'b', 'c']},
    {
        y: 2,
        players: ['x', 'y']},
    {
        y: 4,
        players: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
    ]
}]
```

Now in the **[`tooltip.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter)** you can consume the additional data as follows

```
formatter: function() {
    var result = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</b>';
    $.each(this.points, function(i, datum) {
        result += '<br />' + datum.y + ' players online';
        $.each(datum.point.players, function() {
            result += '<br/>' + this;
        });
    });
    return result;
}
```

**[Complex tooltip | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/k5exP/)**