# Highcharts: passing additional information to a tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have an array of data points that I am passing to a Highcharts chart that looks like

```
mydata = [{
    x: 1,
    y: 3,
    nameList: ["name1", "name2"]
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 4,
    nameList: ["name3", "name4"]
}]
```

I build the chart like this:

```
$("#chart").highcharts("StockChart", {
    series: [{
        data: mydata
    }, {
        data: yourdata
    }]
});
```

Now, I would like to be able to access the nameList array from the shared tooltip, which I'm trying to do as follows:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var s = "";
        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
            s += point.point.nameList;
        });
        return s;
    },
    shared: true
}
```

but when examining the point objects in Firebug using `console.log(point)`, I can't seem to find the nameList entry anywhere in them. How could I access this auxiliary information in a shared series tooltip? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us more from your code? Like how you examine it? I have a suspicion but Im not sure.

Comment: Live example works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/38/

Comment: Hmm, so after some additional testing, it seems like the issue is in the length of the array that I'm dealing with. I saw the turboThreshold option, but changing that doesn't seem to help. I'll keep you guys posted. Thanks for your quick responses, and sorry for getting back so late.
Edit: The arrays I'm working with are of lengths between 500 and 3000.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Additional Data to highcharts series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514457/set-additional-data-to-highcharts-series)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eureka!

By default, Highcharts will accept several different types of input for the data of a series, including

> 1. An array of numerical values. In this case, the numberical values will be interpreted 
>      and y values, and x values will be automatically calculated, either starting at 0 and 
>      incrementing by 1, or from pointStart and pointInterval given in the plotOptions.
> 2. An array of arrays with two values. In this case, the first value is the x value and the 
>      second is the y value. If the first value is a string, it is applied as the name of the 
>      point, and the x value is incremented following the above rules.
> 3. An array of objects with named values. In this case the objects are point configuration 
>      objects as seen below.

However, the treatment of type 3 is different from types 1 and 2: if the array is greater than the turboThreshold setting, then arrays of type 3 won't be rendered. Hence, to fix my problem, I just needed to raise the turboThreshold setting like so:

```
...
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        turboThreshold: longestArray.length + 1
    }
},
...
```

and the chart renders the `longestArray` data properly. Hurray! The only drawback is that there is a considerable time spent rendering the data for much longer arrays due to "expensive data checking and indexing in long series." If any of you know how I might be able to bypass this checking or otherwise be able to speed up the processing of this data, I'd be extremely thankful if you'd let me know how.

Comment: One possibility would be to have an external array and index into it by the x value of the current point, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that... perhaps I should ask another question on SO?

Answer (score 1):

I can see it here:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var s = "";
        console.log(this.points[0].point.nameList); // ["name1", "name2"] 
        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
            s += point.point.nameList;
        });
        return s;
    },
    shared: true
}
```