# highstocks, how can I bring values that I will only use on the 'click' option?

Tags: highcharts

Let me try to explain.

I'm bringing the data:

[1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 2]

But for each one of these there are other values, like time and place. I would like to make a click function like:

```
click: function() {
 testFunction(time.value,place.value);
}
```

Like this, that I click and it will call a javascript function that I could pass these other values? How can I store these values and send it? Where do I store other values, temp values to use in a function?

Found this demo, would be something like that:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax

But I'm not showing anything on the screen, I would like to show only when clicked. this.y and this.x is there on the charts already :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use objects for points.

```
    data:[{
y:10,
additional:'myparametervalue'
},{
y:10,
additional:'myparametervalue'
}]
```

Edit:

Found an answer, with an example and more info about how do it [from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514457/set-additional-data-to-highcharts-series).

Comment: Thank you :), I edited you answer and put a link with more info.

Comment: well, something is strange. If I use more than 1.000 points using this format on highstock the chart does not appear, without showing any error :( , any help?

Comment: just found that if I incput more than 655 'points' the additional values become 'undefined', I think I will create a new question just for that :) , thanks

Comment: You can modify turbothreshold parameter, then you will display more than 1000 points. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold

Comment: Sebastian, thanks, still not working :( , I added the turboThreshold more than my total points and still undefined... Only goes to 655 points :( , I tried the turboThreshold  in the plotOptions series and spline.  Should I create a new question for that?

Comment: Please attach link to jsfiddle

Comment: Created, the interesting thing it's that even with 500 on fiddle I was unable to make it work nice :( , http://jsfiddle.net/gGCFg/ , click on any point it will alert this.y , this.x and my additional values with the undefined

Comment: Thanks for the solution Sebastian, it's fixed :), the fix is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448415/highstock-click-values-undefined