# Highstock, click values undefined

Tags: highcharts

I was working with additional values and click option, got help here
[highstocks, how can I bring values that I will only use on the 'click' option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425857/highstocks-how-can-i-bring-values-that-i-will-only-use-on-the-click-option/17426418)

Everything went fine about the click and additional value

**Then**, I found out that I have problems to return the values if I have more than 655 points on the chart (undefined value). If I limit to less than 655 it appears fine.

Tried using the **turboThreshold**, but no luck. Still undefined value.

I tried include turboThreshold in the plotOptions 'series' nothing. In the plotOptions 'spline' and same thing :(

Does anyone have a clue?

Created a fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/gGCFg/

```
click: function() {
alert(this.x) // data hora
alert(this.y); // valor
alert(this.lat);
    alert(this.long);
}
```

The interesting thing it's that even with 500 on fiddle I was unable to make it work nice :( 
Click on any point it will alert this.y , this.x and my additional values with the undefined.

Thanks

Comment: Please recreate your example in the jsfiddle

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/gGCFg/ , thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable datagrouping

http://jsfiddle.net/gGCFg/1/

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

```
dataGrouping:{
                enabled:false
            },
```