# Highcharts - additional data with Json

Tags: json, highcharts

I'm using json to load the charts. I need now to show additional data in the tooltip. I see this example: [Set Additional Data to highcharts series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514457/set-additional-data-to-highcharts-series)

In my page I'm loading a json like this...

[{y:5,test:"test"},{....}]

and in the js file. I tried this :

var options = {
        chart: {....};

options.series[0].data =  json;

When I try to load the charts, it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you receive any errors, could you attach full example of your chart / code, because it is only piece.

Comment: I already found the answer, that is below. Besides I wasn't getting any errors. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Json is produced by an ASP page. I solved the problem with this..

```
<%Response.ContentType = "application/json"%>
```

=D