# Highcharts custom attribute with datetime line chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart with `xAxis` values as timestamps and `yAxis` values has a number. The definition is easy:

```
xAxis : [ {
    type : 'datetime'
    labels: {
        formatter: function(){
            // Custom function formatting timestamps
        }
    }
]
```

Data from my API come like this and works great.

```
data:[
    [1558648800, 10256],
    [1558648801, 10258],
    [1558648802, 10259]
]
```

The issue now is that I need to show a message in a tooltip, so I found some solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/8515679.

```
data: [
    {y : 10256, myData : 'Message 1'},
    {y : 10258, myData : 'Message 2'},
    {y : 10259, myData : 'Message 3'}
]
```

In this solution `xAxis` data dissapears so the unique way that I found is using `name` attribute as `xAxis`, but I thought that is not the best while managing timestamps and autommatic `tikcIntervals`.

(I delegate intervals on Highcharts, doesn't matter).

So my question is, what it would be the best way to create that extra attribute (myData) for tooltip, considering datetime with timestamps line chart?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data with `x`, `y` and `myData` properties:

```
series: [{
    data: [{
            x: 1558648800,
            y: 10256,
            myData: 'Message 1'
        },
        {
            x: 1558648801,
            y: 10258,
            myData: 'Message 2'
        },
        {
            x: 1558648802,
            y: 10259,
            myData: 'Message 3'
        }
    ]
}]
```

Or define the data as an array and use `keys` property:

```
series: [{
    keys: ['x', 'y', 'myData'],
    data: [
        [1558648800, 10256, 'Message 1'],
        [1558648801, 10258, 'Message 2'],
        [1558648802, 10259, 'Message 3']
    ],
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nsw46pLx/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.keys

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm! The key is `keys` attribute!!! This is what I was looking for. Thanks!